# Assigning an integer into index in char * pointer array

Tags: c++, arrays, char, c-strings

Redoing my previous question since I didn't provide enough detail.

I have a char pointer array, `char* token[100]`. Let's say I have a double-digit number, like 33.

How do I assign this int into an index in the token array, so that when I print out that token it will give me 33 and not some sort of ASCII value?

```
char* token[100];
int num = 33;
//How do I assign num into a specific token index, like for example:
token[1] = num;
//When I print out that token index, I want 33 to be printed out
cout << token[1] << endl; // I want to have 33 be the result. Right now I have '!' as an output
```

Comment: Just cast back to an integer before printing?

Comment: First you need to understand that a `char*` is a pointer to a location in memory.  You have set it to the value 33, which almost certainly isn't within your program's address space.  Then you are trying to read a string which you incorrectly assume is stored in that memory location and write it to standard out.

Comment: Do you mean you want to print out `33` and not `42`?

Comment: @John Yes, sorry, that's a typo

Comment: @AlanBirtles The printing is just an example. Let's say I want to pass that number in the array to another method. I don't want to have to cast it there. Is there a way to not have to cast it out and have the actual integer enter the array?

Comment: Do you know the difference between a `char *[]` and a `char []`? Do you know the difference between a `char` and an `int`? Do you know what an array is? We're asking these questions so we can direct you to the best resources. We need to gauge your level of understanding.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use an array of `int`s? What is your application?

Comment: @John a char *[] is an array of char addresses in memory (I believe), while a char []  is just an array of chars. A char is a data type which is a character, and an int is an integer

Comment: @John I can't just use an array of ints because my program also deals with chars

Comment: @madaniloff okay, that's correct. But I'm confused as to why you store an arbitrary `int` as a `char *`. Normally when we print out memory addresses its to do some kind of weird structure or pointer debugging.

Comment: @John I'm going to be passing these chars into different methods, but maybe it is just better to go with a normal char array.

Comment: @madaniloff It is most assuredly better to use a `char []`. What range of values do you want to store in this array? `char` is likely only able to store between hexadecimal `0x00` and `0xff`. If you try to assign an integer value greater than 255 or less than 0 to an element in your array, then it will be truncated.

Comment: @John even when I change the token array to a regular char array, when I try to assign num to token[i] I still get an ASCII value out. How would I convert 33 to like a string and then assign it to that index?

Comment: @madaniloff Information is data + context. A `char []` named `token` with `token[1] = 33` gives both the data (decimal 33) and the context (treat this like a character). If your context is actually that you want these things treated like numbers, than use an integer type. Use a `uint8_t []` if you're using unsigned 8 bit integer. Or use `int []` if you want an array of integers. Then they'll output using `cout` as you expect.

Comment: @John The token array, however, doesn't just have numbers. It has chars in there as well. I basically just want the int 33 to be treated like a string '33' in the array.

Comment: @madaniloff You can fit a char into an int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you mean something like the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

int main() 
{
    char * token[100] = {};
    int num = 33;

    std::string s= std::to_string( num );

    token[1] = new char[s.size() + 1];

    std::strcpy( token[1], s.c_str() );

    std::cout << "token[1] = " << token[1] << '\n';

    delete [] token[1];

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
token[1] = 33
```

If you are not allowed to use C++ containers and functions then the program can look the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

int main() 
{
    char * token[100] = {};
    int num = 33;

    char buffer[12];

    std::sprintf( buffer, "%d", num );

    token[1] = new char[std::strlen( buffer ) + 1];

    std::strcpy( token[1], buffer );

    std::cout << "token[1] = " << token[1] << '\n';

    delete [] token[1];

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ah, thank you! That is what I meant. However, my teacher doesn't allow me to use the std:: commands, so is there a way to do this that doesn't use those?

Comment: To handle all 32-bit `int`, `char buffer[12];`  makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

I'm convinced, from comments, that you want an array of integer types. If we get further clarification about why this needs to be a `char` array, I'll update my answer, but from all available information it seems like you really want an integer-type array.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int token[100] = {};
    int num = 33;

    token[1] = num;

    std::cout << token[1] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This needs to be a char array because I am reading in an equation like this (3 + 34 x 7) and I need to basically have each number in its own array for example: token[3][+][34][x][7].

Comment: If your equation was `3 + 256` what tokens would be stored in the `char` array? A char is usually only 8 bits, so that 256 will overflow if you try to store it as a single `char`.

Comment: ok maybe I don't completely understand chars but I thought that 256 would be treated as a string and would just be token[256]

Comment: @madaniloff What is the input and output of your program? Do you need to solve the typed in equation? Because the equation `3 + 34 x 7` would be stored as the character array {3, 43, 34, 120, 7}. After storing it in an array, how can you tell which of those `char`s are operators and which are numbers?

Comment: Basically I am taking user input from a char, so, for example, input would be input[3][+][34][x][7]. If the number is a single digit or operator I am just assigning it to the token array like this token[i] = input[i].